# Change uint8 grayscale image to a floating point for learning

Tags: matlab, image-processing, type-conversion, computer-vision, neural-network

My goal is to make a vector of (1,250x250) for learning in a Neural Network. I am converting 250x250 jpg images to grayscale in matlab. The result is `<250x250 uint8>`. My question is how do I convert the `uint8` vector into `float32`?

Comment: I think you mean `uint8`...

Comment: `double` typically refers to a 64bit floating point number and single to a 32bit floating point number. What do you mean?

Comment: @Amir - `float32` is NOT `double`: `float32` is a single precision floating point number (takes 4 bytes in memory), while `double` is a double precision floating point number that takes double that space - 8 bytes.

Comment: @Shai Oops, sorry my bad ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert a `uint8` type array into 32 bit floating point you can simply:

```
for_learning = single( gray_imag );
```

`for_learning` is a single precision 250x250 image with pixel values in range [0..255]. If you want pixel values to range in the interval [0..1], you simply need to divide it

```
for_learning = single( gray_imag )/ 255.0;
```

See [`single`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/single.html) and [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) for more information

Comment: Or `im2single` / `im2double` to have the scaling done automatically.